# Can not login to Azure SQL with new user

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I want to create a new user with certain permissions for an Azure Sql database, but I can not log in with it. From my understanding the necessary steps to create a new user and login are to create a login first:

```
CREATE LOGIN myLogin
  WITH PASSWORD = 'myPw' 
GO
```

After that I create a new user for the non-master database and add him to roles:

```
CREATE USER myUser
  FOR LOGIN myLogin
  WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO


EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'myUser'
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'myUser'
GO
```

When I now try to login using the username `myUser` with password `myPw` I get the error message

```
Login failed for user 'myUser'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)
```

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Did you create the `LOGIN` in the `Master` database? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins

Comment: Yes, the login is in the master database and the user in the specific non-master database

Comment: Have you created an entry on the firewall of the Azure SQL Database? How are you trying to connect to the database? Are you using SSMS

Comment: The IP of the machine is in the firewall. I tried it using SSMS, OSQL and an UDL file. Logging in on the same machine with SSMS as DB-Admin works.

Comment: When you connect with SSMS, try to make a click on the Options button, and specify the user database on the "Connect to database" field.

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo Thanks for the hint, as I did not know how to do that in SMSS. It did not help though and I specified the database in my other tries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this issue. Were you able to resolve it?. I was trying to use a login to keep database user passwords synced but it is not working at all, so creating the user with password directly in the non-master database worked for me.

```
if not exists(select * from sys.database_principals where name = 'my_user')
begin
    exec('create user [my_user] with password = ''my_pwd'', default_schema = dbo')
end
go

-- Give specific roles to new database user
alter role db_ddladmin add member [my_user]
alter role db_datareader add member [my_user]
alter role db_datawriter add member [my_user]
go

-- Assure you give connect access to the user, otherwise may not be able to login
grant connect to [my_user]
go
```

Comment: please questions as comments and not anwers